# Git push to origin master appears to succeed but nothing changes

Tags: git

I am attempting to push to a remote bare repository. I make local commits successfully but whenever I push to origin/master the changes are not reflected in the remote repo.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 360 bytes | 360.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To <remote/path>
   3a25c0d..fc7b327  master -> master

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Edit: I believe branch fix-detached-HEAD was something I created in an attempt to solve this after some Googling.

```
$ git remote -vvv
origin  <remote path> (fetch)
origin  <remote path> (push)


$ git branch -vvv
  fix-detached-HEAD 47f1938 <commit message 1>
* master            fc7b327 [origin/master] <latest commit message>
```

Edit: Remote bare confirmation:

```
$ git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
true
```

Comment: This output looks good. How do you check the remote repo, and who is the host? Could you post the output of `git remote -vvv` and `git branch -vvv`?

Comment: The local master branch is already having latest changes so when you push changes to remote you will see the new commits on the remote. Locally you will see nothing much changed coz it already has the latest changes. You need to check on the remote to see if new commits are pushed there.

Comment: @wjandrea see edit

Comment: @NathanFarmer On the remote? No, you need to run those commands on the local.

Comment: On the remote it's showing you it got the pushed commit, it was 3a25,now it's fc7b.

Comment: @wjandrea oops I'm a n00b...see latest edit

Comment: OK, everything looks good... How do you know the changes are not reflected in the remote repo? Like jthill said, the commits are there...

Comment: @wjandrea I have full access to both repos and can see the code is the same and the timestamp on the remote files hasn't updated

Comment: Wait, how are you viewing the code? Isn't the remote bare?

Comment: @wjandrea I tested the remote and confirmed it is bare per the edit. I just open the files from the remote location in an editor as usual.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to ask, what code? The remote is bare. It contains objects, not source code.

Comment: @wjandrea so you are telling me these files on the remote are useless? I just cloned the remote back to local and saw the changes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199712/discussion-between-wjandrea-and-nathan-farmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/199712), ultimately the problem is that you set up the remote in a weird way, first copying your source code files to it, running `git init`, then converting it to bare (and cloning to local). However it seems like you forgot to delete the files when converting to bare, so when you pushed and were expecting them to be updated, they weren't. Git ignores errant files in a bare repo, but continues to update the objects and other components. (As [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018746/git-push-to-origin-master-appears-to-succeed-but-nothing-changes/58029931#comment102442305_58018746), the pushes were received, based on [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58018746/3) of the question.)

If you actually do want your source code files to exist on the remote, see [eis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365237/eis)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022041/4518341), but this is a more advanced usage and as a newbie, you probably want just a regular bare repo. To avoid future confusion, I might suggest removing your existing remote and starting fresh, but make a backup first.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, you are looking at some files on the remote that are either not part of your repo, or part of a separate checkout. That explains why they are not updated, because you're updating the bare repo with objects on the remote and not the files you're looking at.

If you want git push to actually deploy the files on the remote server, one way of doing that is setting up a hook on the remote server, like explained in [this link](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-website-to-remote-server-using-git-da6048805637):

> 5. Create Hook
>
>    A Hook is a program you can place in a hooks directory to trigger actions at certain points in git’s execution.
>
> Git has several hooks that it can call after different stages automatically. You will use the post-receive hook which is called after your repository has received pushed code.
>
> After initialising your git repository, new folders should appear inside /var/repo/website.git/. Navigate to hooks and create a new bash called post-receive using your preferred text editor.
>
> cd hooks nano post-receive
>
> Inside of the newly created file, you need to tell git where to put
>   the files pushed. To do so, paste the following code:
>
> `#!/bin/sh`
>
> `git --work-tree=path_to_website_folder --git-dir=path_to_git_directory
>   checkout -f name_of_branch`
>
> replace path_to_website_folder with the correct path /var/www/website_folder which we created in point 3.
>      replace path_to_git_directory with the path to the bare git repository, which in this case is /var/repo/website.git.
>      name_of_branch is an optional parameter. If not specified, it defaults to master.
>
> You can follow that script with any other commands of your choice,
>   like restarting the server for instance.
>
> Quit the editor using ctrl+x, and make sure to save the file as
>   post-receive.
>
> 6. Make the script executable
>
> In order for the operating system to execute the script, the latter
>   needs to have executable permissions. To do so run the following
>   command:
>
> `chmod +x post-receive`
>
> The work on your server is done. You can now logout by simply running
>   logout and hitting Return

Answer (score 0):

Your results show that you aren't actually pushing to a remote repository.

```
$ git remote -vvv
<no results - blank>
```

You need to add an upstream.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Then check `git remote -v` again. You should see something like

```
origin git@github.com:username/repo.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:username/repo.git (push)
```

When you push now it should go to that location.

You may also have to do

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

the first time.

Comment: OP ran `git remote -vvv` *on the remote*, hence your confusion

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm not quite sure why that was requested... @OP what does the remote look like on the local? (from local do `git remote -v`). I'm still not convinced OP has a connection to the upstream.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of "git push" try "git push -u origin master" in this -u stands for update may be this could solve your problem.

Comment: you can see from the output that it is pushing master to origin/master already. and `-u` does not stand for "update", but "set upstream"...